# OpenGL ES2 coloured triangle

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I am trying to make basic triangle in opengl es 2, but whatever I do, it just doesn't seem to be working.. All I get is a white triangle. However, I think there might be a problem
when linking the program (that's I have disabled return from linking checking "if", otherwise it won't run at all). Also, when I run with the console, I get in the output "error: 1281". My code:

```
int loadShader(int type, char * shaderCode)
{
    int length = strlen(shaderCode);

    int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, (const char **) &shaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

// Initializes the application data
int Init(void) 
{
    // Vertex shaders
    char * vertexShaderCode = 
        "attribute vec4 vPosition; \n" 
        "void main() {             \n" 
        " gl_Position = vPosition; \n"  
        "}                         \n";

    char * fragmentShaderCode = 
        "precision mediump float;                 \n"
        "void main() {                            \n"
        " gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);\n"
        "}                                        \n";

    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    GLuint fragmentShader = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);
    GLint linked;

    program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vPosition");
    glLinkProgram(program);

    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);

    if(!linked)
    {
       GLint infoLen = 0;
       glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
       if(infoLen > 1)
       {
          char* infoLog = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);
          glGetProgramInfoLog(program, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
          free(infoLog);
       }
       glDeleteProgram(program);
       //return 0;
    }

    // Basic GL setup
    glClearColor    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    return GL_TRUE;
}



// Main-loop workhorse function for displaying the object
void Display(void)
{
    // Clear the screen
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);   


    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    };

    GLfloat colors[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };


    glUseProgram(program);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,  0, 3);
}
```

Comment: Try to find which line of code generates the error.

Comment: Have you tried logging to see what happens? There is `glGetShaderInfoLog` to get information about shader programs. Also for opengl, see glGetError

Comment: @Tim, easier said than done. I tried adding exit function and traced it to linked if, it looks like it enters it, but skips infoLen, so I really have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Use vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) instead of vec4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f) maybe the gray looks on your monitor more white. And try it again without: glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors); glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); Hope this will help :)

Comment: error: 1281 == Invalid Value, so one line of your c/c++ code is "wrong". Use a debugger or use printf("Step: %d\n", glGetError()) (or similar) after each gl operation. If the value is something else as 0 (GL_NO_ERROR), there is the error.

Comment: you don't print your shader log! do it :)

Comment: Ok, I tried changing to blue, still nothing. I have now added "logging" to file, but I have no idea how to print glGetError as it is GLenum and it won't allow me to write to file. Also, I tried googling and found that there might be a problem with my gpu (intel hd).

Comment: Only print GLenum as a integer. The integer representation can you see [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_Error_Codes). Hmm, I have no intel hd so I can not check that :(

Comment: I run your code (with a additional main) and saw a blue triangle. So I think it is a driver bug or one of your additional code is broken (so the failure is not here) :) Maybe try a OpenGL Debugger?

Comment: Hm, that's strange. I tried debugging shaders and they don't even compile. The error I'm getting is "lloca memory reserved by this function is corrupted" whatever that means. But if you say that loadShader function is correct, then what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

enable the vertex attrib array first and then pass the pointers...

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);    
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,  0, 3);
```

Also you are sending colors in the "1" attrib array but there is no such attrib in the shader.

Comment: But it's still white triangle. I don't think that's the problem. Could it be something wrong with shaders because it doesn't read "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);"?

Comment: for me the white clour indicates that the shaders are not working... and opengl uses its own fallback code to rasterize. maybe you could debug those saders in gDebugger or some RenderMonkey? Another suggestion: what with preccision for vertex attribute? shouldn't it be a attrib mediump vec4 vPostion? And what does line " "precision mediump float;  " mean? there is no variable name!?

Comment: http://www.webreference.com/programming/opengl_es/2.html
It's in the fragment shader and it's in a lot of tutorials, so it's probably correct.